# Changing ProjectGUID inside C# or VB.NET Project Files

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I've been working on this Solution for a while now, but suddenly I'm getting lots of errors in the Output window when I compile..

```
There was a problem reading metadata from '{AD2B7AC6-357A-46BC-96B8-489C4CCDDEDF}' 
('The system cannot find the file specified.'). 
IntelliSense may not work properly until the solution is reloaded.
```

Using a search through the Directories related to the project I notice that most of the project files all have the same GUID. When I inherited this project it had started life as a VS2005 project then Updated to VS2008, and now I've updated it to VS2010. I'm wondering if something has gone wrong during the conversions.

```
  C:\Development\Projects\KitchenMonitor\ConnectionTest\ConnectionTest.vbproj (1 hits)
    Line 177:       [Project]{AD2B7AC6-357A-46BC-96B8-489C4CCDDEDF}[/Project]
  C:\Development\Projects\KitchenMonitor\DatabaseManager\DatabaseManager.vbproj (1 hits)
    Line 170:       [Project]{AD2B7AC6-357A-46BC-96B8-489C4CCDDEDF}[/Project]
  C:\Development\Projects\KitchenMonitor\MainApplication\IKM.vbproj (1 hits)
    Line 672:       [Project]{AD2B7AC6-357A-46BC-96B8-489C4CCDDEDF}[/Project]
  C:\Development\Projects\KitchenMonitor\Library\Library.vbproj (1 hits)
    Line 8:     [Project]{AD2B7AC6-357A-46BC-96B8-489C4CCDDEDF}[/Project]
  C:\Development\Projects\KitchenMonitor\Tests\Tests.vbproj (1 hits)
    Line 118:       [Project]{AD2B7AC6-357A-46BC-96B8-489C4CCDDEDF}[/Project]
  C:\Development\Projects\KitchenMonitor\WPFDisplay\WPFDisplay.csproj (1 hits)
    Line 99:       [Project]{AD2B7AC6-357A-46BC-96B8-489C4CCDDEDF}[/Project]
```

Without going fully back through SourceControl (early version in VSS 2005) newer versions in Subversion, will it be ok to just edit the files and set the GUIDS to be unique for each project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It will be OK to do that. However you will have to remove each changed project from your solution and re-add it so that the sln file correctly records the new project GUIDs.

Comment: Just be careful if you've used the sln file to customize the build order etc cause if you remove the project those customizations will get lost.

Comment: I wonder if this issue is what these people are seeing http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/16c8026e-2dbc-4d62-b8a2-36a690e1c406/